# Why doesn't the stl vector store my class object with the correct values?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I'm using a vector `v` to store a class object called `t_display`. I've checked with the debugger and I can see the display object is instantiated correctly. However, when I pass it into the vector with `v.push_back()` or `v.insert()`, it stores every value as `-842150451`. I can see this in the print statements and in the debugger and I cant figure out why it's storing the object this way. Additionally, its storing the integer values this way every time i execute the program, which leads me to believe its not a memory issue although i cant be sure. I've checked all over stack overflow and cppreference. Any advice would be appreciated.
here is the class where I create the object and pass into the vector. I just want the vector to contain the newly made object t_display at the first element.

### Animation.cpp

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;

#include "Display.h"
#include "Animation.h"


void Animation::InsertFrame() {

    int numDisplays;
    vector <Display>v;
    int p_x;
    int p_y=0;
    int p_duration=0;
    string p_name;
    string frameName;

    cout << "Insert a Frame in the Animation\nPlease enter the Frame filename" << endl;
    cin >> frameName;
    cout << "Entering the Frame Displays (the sets of dimensions and durations) " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of Displays :" << endl;
    cin >> numDisplays;
    vector <Display>::iterator it;
    it = v.begin();

    while (numDisplays > 0) {
        cout << "Please enter pixel x for Display #0 pixel_x:";
        cin >> p_x;
        cout << "\nPlease enter pixel y for Display #0 pixel_y:" << endl;
        cin >> p_y;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the duration sec for this Display :" << endl;
        cin >> p_duration;
        cout << "\nPlease enter the name for this Display : " << endl;
        cin >> p_name;
        Display t_display =  Display(p_x, p_y, p_duration, (char *)p_name.c_str());
        //it = v.insert(it, t_display);
        v.push_back(t_display);
        numDisplays--;
    }
```

### Display.h

```
    // Display.h
    #pragma once

    class Display
    {
        int pixel_x;
        int pixel_y;
        int duration;
        char* name;
    public:
        Display(int x, int y, int duration, char* name);
        Display(const Display&);
        ~Display();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Display&);
    };


## Display.cpp ##

#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
using namespace std;
#include "Display.h"
int q = 0;
Display::Display(int x, int y, int d, char* n):pixel_x(x), pixel_y(y), duration(d), name(n) {}
Display::Display(const Display&) {

}
Display::~Display() {

}
```

Comment: Where are you displaying it

Comment: I would recommend using std::string to store the name in the `Display` class, or use string functions to dynamically create a string (`char*`) then copy the string over. I believe this may be the issue. It seems you are only copying the pointer and not the actual string when you do push_back.

Comment: `Display` copy constructor doesn't actually copy anything, but leaves all members uninitialized. This is what you observe.

Comment: `(char *)p_name.c_str()` is invalidated on the next loop iteration. You should use `string` instead. Needing C-style cast is a big red flag (as is using a raw pointer)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I didn't write a copy constructor.